How to Call a Function Needed for a File listed under setupFiles in Jest?
I'm using setupFiles in Jest to call an authentication flow for a new test framework.  As part of that effort I've started abstracting common request types to a separate file, then referencing them in my auth setup file.
But for some reason the function is called without passing any arguments.
jest.config.cjs
setupFiles: ['./tests/lib/auth.cjs'],

auth.cjs
const request = require('./requests.cjs');
const microsoftLoginUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/';

async function getAuthCookie() {
    // Login
    const loginResponse = await request.post(
      `${microsoftLoginUrl}xxxxx/login`,
      {
        login: 'xxxx',
        passwd: 'xxxxx',
        canary: canary,
        ctx: ctx,
        hpgRequestId: sessionId,
        flowToken: sft,
      },
      {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    );

requests.cjs
async function post(url, body, headers) {
  body.headers = headers;
  const postConstants = { method: 'POST', body: new URLSearchParams({ body }) };
  return await fetch(url, postConstants);
}

module.exports = post();


module.exports = post() exports the result of post, not the function itself. In case this is not the intention, it should be
module.exports = post;

And it should be imported like:
const post = require('./requests.cjs');


The only issue I get with this is Jest will tell me post is not a function.  For some reason adding the brackets fixes this.

These are not just the brackets. It's not a function in original code indeed because you're calling it in requests.cjs, post() is a promise. Can you verify you get "not a function" with the suggested fix too?

Verified, your solution does not work.  I'm pretty sure I included all relevant code.

You need to import it accordingly. I updated the post for clarity

That's it!  Thought I tried it, apparently not..

Glad it worked. In case you "plan to add other request types" as you noted, the way you did will require less changes in the future. Can also be exports.post = async function post...

Not exactly sure why, but changing my export and import fixes it.  So:
module.exports = { post };
const { post } = require('./requests.cjs');
const loginResponse = await post();
I would prefer not to use brackets with requests only having a single function, but I do plan to add other request types, so I guess it's ok.

You don't need to use brackets - see the answer provided by Estus.
